# call template thymeleaf form with 2 differents controller method

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would like to know if is possible to find in my template thymleaf  which method from the controller call this template ?

Because i need to use my template in two method and the form of this template will change in fonction of the method of controller

Thank for the answers

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is that you send a boolean variable through the model and use th:if in the template.

Comment: Yes, is a very good idea, Thank you very much , it was really helpful